# Guava cache get and put behavior

Tags: java, caching, guava

I know there is lot of documentation on Guava `Cache`, but haven't been able to find a clear answer to this Q - An entry exists in cache already and I overwrite the entry with - 
`cache.put(K,V)`

If another thread calls `cache.get(K)` at the same time, what does the cache return? Is it blocked till `put()` completes writing or does it return the old value? Any helpful links/pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guava's `Cache` classes are based on `ConcurrentHashMap` and therefore share its basic behaviour.

I don't think it's a part of the contract, but it's mentioned in [one of the docs](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). To make sure, I looked at the source code and it indeed is the case - the code is actually branched from `ConcurrentHashMap`. We will have to have somebody from the Guava team chime in to be absolutely sure there are no corner cases where this might be false, so I'll just silently assume it's always right.

With this in mind, the answer is easy - the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) docs say:

> Retrieval operations (including `get()`) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including `put()` and `remove()`). Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently *completed* update operations
>   holding upon their onset. For aggregate operations such as `putAll()` and
>   `clear()`, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only
>   some entries.

Therefore, in your particular case, the `get()` call will *not* block and will *most likely* return the old value.